# How do I display array object information?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

```
    <html>
<head>

<script>

var contacts =[];

function getInfo() {
    var firstName = prompt("Enter first name");
    var lastName = prompt("Enter last name");
    var emailId = prompt("Enter Email ID");
    var phoneNo = prompt("Enter Phone number");

    var person ={
        fname : firstName,
        lname : lastName,
        email : emailId,
        phone : phoneNo
    };


    contacts.push(person);  

    var currPerson = contacts[contacts.length-1]; //take last pushed object from the array

        if(currPerson.lname.toUpperCase().charAt(0)==='Z'){

        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML +=currPerson.fname+" "+currPerson.lname + '<br/>';
        }



}

</script>

<body>

<button onclick="getInfo()">Get Person Info</button>
<p>----------------------------</p>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Output]

> When I click on billa zopper, his **details(full name,phone and email)** should appear on right hand side in the same page. How do I achieve this? I know DOM is an option. But how do I link the DOM with the array elements?

Comment: Depends on what element(s) you're writing to. What's wrong with what you posted here? Are you unsure how to "foreach" the array to write all the names?

Comment: It works, but only if the last name starts with a capital Z

Comment: @Nikki9696 I will have n number of contacts. If I select any name in the list, then information(full name,phone,email)  should be displayed. In the above code, I am just printing the current element, I don't have track of previous element to display other information using onClick( ). How do I associate this with DOM to print fullName,email,phone ?

Comment: Are the names always coming from user input? Or is this a mock up of something that comes from a service or web request?

Comment: @Nikki9696   Yes, names always coming from user input.

Comment: I see. I think I'd just add an id field. Let me come up with a little example.

Comment: Did you mean to only write info for people who have last names that start with Z?

Comment: I'll have to do this from A-Z. I'm experimenting with 'z' first. @Nikki9696

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105409/discussion-between-droidr-and-nikki9696).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a correlation of the array index to make this a simple example. I feel the need to point out that this is not how I'd actually implement anything in a real world application. But you asked for how to make it show things in a side div on click, so here we are.

```
<button onclick="getInfo()">Get Person Info</button>
<p>----------------------------</p>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="target" style="float: right;">
</div>


var contacts =[];
function getInfo() {
    var firstName = prompt("Enter first name");
    var lastName = prompt("Enter last name");
    var emailId = prompt("Enter Email ID");
    var phoneNo = prompt("Enter Phone number");


     var person ={
        id: contacts.length,
        fname : firstName,
        lname : lastName,
        email : emailId,
        phone : phoneNo
    };

    contacts.push(person);
    var currPerson = contacts[contacts.length-1];
    if(currPerson.lname.toUpperCase().charAt(0)==='Z') {        
            document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<span onclick='showMe(" + currPerson.id + ")'>" + currPerson.fname + " " + currPerson.lname + "</span><br/>";

    }
 }

function showMe(id) {
   var person = contacts[id];  /* currently corresponds to array index, could be a property lookup with underscore or whatever */
   target.innerHTML = "<div>" + person.fname + "</div>";
}
```

Comment: "not how I'd actually implement anything in a real world" ... up vote for making me laugh. :D

Comment: =) well there are far better ways to do this sorta thing, but then I'd be writing the whole app. And for all I know, someone told him to do it this way like for homework or something so...

Comment: @Nikki9696 It shows only person.fname? Can I make it display full information(full name,email,phone) ? I tried , But it showing only the last one.

Comment: @Nikki9696 In  `document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<span onclick='showMe(" + currPerson.id + ")'>" + currPerson.fname + " " + currPerson.lname + "</span><br/>";` Can you explain what is **currPerson.id** is? I know it is passing an array index, But can't understand how it's working.

Comment: I borrowed the positional index of the array for the id property. You could use anything, like a GUID or an id from a database as well. I set it at the same time I set name. It's how I look up the person in the array in order to display the details. If you used a GUID or other info, you'd have to look it up a little more complicated than using the index as I did. There are underscore.js methods to look up array item by property value. I would use that.